# As what does phrase "to make me laugh" function in this example? (as an adjective or an adverb)

Tags: phrases, prepositional-phrases

[a video with title "Phrases" of a grammar teaching yt channel](https://youtu.be/W7XoOM1lqf0)

(minute 6:35)

Speaking person in the video has written the sentence "I am looking for a book to make me laugh" and he claims that phrase "to make me laugh" is functioning as an adjective of noun "a book". But I think that phrase "to make me laugh" is functioning as an adverb of verb "to look for".

What do you think? Which one of us is right?

Comment: Presumably it is not looking that makes you laugh, but the book itself.

Comment: @WeatherVane I've just understood, thank you. "How a book?", "a book to make me laugh"(a book which will make me laugh).

Answer (score 1):

The person in the video is correct.

The example speaker isn't "looking laughingly", they are are looking for a specific kind of book. "a book to make me laugh".

If it were an adverb it would modify the way they were looking, not what they were looking for.